# Committed user listed twice in Games Development proposal

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, commitment-phase

[Committed user listed twice in Games Development proposal http://img833.imageshack.us/img833/4271/icelandbug.jpg](http://img833.imageshack.us/img833/4271/icelandbug.jpg)

Comment: It's always Game Day in Iceland.

Comment: Wow, he's really committed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Olafur has multiple personalities, both of them game developers.

There are *some* differences between them. One of them likes to make soap and start underground fighting rings (but we're not supposed to talk about that).

Comment: <3 ......... <3

Answer (score 2):

Clearly he will be participating as much as two people would.

I see no bug here....