# Site proposal allowing multiple commits from a single user

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, commitment

It looks to me like one user has committed to the [Application Security proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/8431/application-security) twice. At the time of this writing, the commits are viewable on [this page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/8431?page=2&phase=commitment&committers=totalreputation#tab-top). At first glance, this looks like a dupe of [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57825/committed-user-listed-twice-in-games-development-proposal), but the behavior is actually slightly different in that the rep totals and badges do not match up as they did in the earlier bug. The hash-generated Gravatar does, though. Clicking on the username to the first commit goes to [this profile](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/18306/moshe); the second one goes to [this one](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/16930/moshe). Maybe something got cached wrong somewhere?

EDIT:
The fix didn't take hold on SO: the user still has two accounts there ([one](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224988/moshe), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/users/493943/moshe)). Some more details can be found in [the chat transcript](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/conversation/moshe-account-bug-report).

EDIT 2:
Apparently this [is being resolved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69167/my-account-is-crippled-openid-to-blame), so we can all feel good about the `[status-completed]` on this post again.

Comment: In addition to having matching avatars, the two profiles appear to have identical sets of associated accounts on the accounts tab.

Comment: That's the important part; accounts can have matching gravatars, but this seems to be two different accounts associated with the same set of accounts, which should be impossible

Comment: @moberley, thanks for the assist, I was nearly asleep when I posted this last night.

Comment: @Michael, you're right, of course, though I think it's highly unlikely that an e-mail-hash-based gravatar would be duplicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like the same user with two accounts (since the email and several other details were identical).  I've merged the two accounts.  Since there doesn't seem to be any other evidence of foul play, I'll assume it was an honest mistake on their part.